# alturnitives to dynamicly declaining variable names automaticly in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, variables, dynamic, naming

i searched online to find out how to dynamically declare variable names automatically and i came up with no results. my approach to the code i'm simplifying is as follows:

```
dim choice1 as string
dim choice2 as string
dim choice3 as string
...
```

i wish i can approch this as follows

```
dim count as integer
while count is 1 to 10
   count +=1
end while
dim (choice+count) as string
' it suppose to create variable choice with the addition to the name from 1    to 10 like choice1, choice2, choice3 and so on.
```

can you help me.

ps: i also tried creating declared variables in an array like so:

```
dim count as integer
Dim var As Array = {Dim choice1 as string, dim choice2 as string}
while count is 1 to 10
     var.add(dim choice+count as string)
end while
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of operation are not supported in VB .NET (as far as I know of, correct me if I'm wrong, that will make me smarter...)

However, you can declare a Dictionary(of String, Object) that will hold the values you want to keep.

Let's say you want to create ten Strings:

```
Dim myvars as New Dictionary(of String, String)

For i = 1 to 10
  myVars.Add("choice" & i, "New String Value")
Next

'Next you can access these vars like this
Dim choice = "choice5"
Dim string5 = myVars(choice)
myvars(choice) = "Replaced"
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally this pattern is addressed using arrays. Now days you could use lists, dictionaries, etc. Most developers would use something like this:

```
Dim choice(10) as String
'choice(0) is same as choice0
'choice(1) is same as choice1
'choice(2) is same as choice2
'choice(3) is same as choice3
'etc.
```